# Wamp Error - aestan tray menu the confuguration file contains a syntax error on line 14:

Tags: wamp, wampserver, trayicon

I was just installed WAMPServer. After open my pc I have this issue.

[image]

My wampmanager.ini

```
[BigMenu]
BigKey0=NC,0,0
[TextMenu]
TextKey0=NC,0,8,$000ff9f2,$00D77800,NC,NC
[PromptCustom]
PromptKey0=Default,10,$00FCFDFE,$00000000,$00FCFDFE,$00000000
PromptKey1=NC,10,$00F0F0F0,$00000000,$00FCFDFE,$00000000
[Timer]
NumberStart=2
CountStart=0
[Options]
AeTrayMode=64 Bits
AeTrayOldMode=64bit
AeTrayVersion=3.2.3.3
```

Comment: Did you read the first Dialog shown in the install? It says you need to make sure you have the multiple MSVC Runtimes installed. I dont think you do. Go to the [Backup WAMPServer Repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) and at the bottom of the page there is a download link for ALL the MSVC runtimes you may need.. If you are using Windows 64bit you shoudl install the 32bit AND the 64 bit MSVC Runtimes

Comment: Then you will probably have to uninstall WAMPServer and then reinstall it. Without the correct MSVC RUntimes some of the install will fail

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@[aspectsiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15632088/aspectsiz) just to clarify what @[El Ibrahima Diago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8391027/el-ibrahima-diago) has written try the following.

### Find your WAMP/SCRIPTS directory

Find where your WAMP > Scripts directory is.
*For myself it's located at: C:\wamp64\scripts*

### Load Command Prompt

Load command prompt and CD into your WAMP > Scripts directory

### Execute The Command

Execute: php refresh.php

That should be all that's required to fix it. I had the exact same issue and it has worked for me.

---

Just to recap, here is the full Command Prompt commands that I used:

*cd C:\wamp64\scripts*

*php refresh.php*

I hope that might clear a few things up and help others a bit more.

Comment: on the **php refresh.php** command I get : _'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file._

Answer (score 0):

For this problem you juste have to go to wamp/scripts/ and type this command php refresh.php

Comment: Please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your answer properly to indicate the path and the command name appropriately